# Using Jsoup (or other 3rd party jars) in Android

Tags: android, import

This is the first time I've used a 3rd party jar, but it seems like I'm doing everything right.  I'm using Jsoup to parse HTML.

In my project, under `Properties->Java Build Path` I have added the external jsoup jar.  Under `Order and Export` I have tried jsoup both checked and unchecked.  Seems to have made no difference.  When writing my app, eclipse was able to find the right imports, autocomplete methods/constructors.  Eclipse seems to see Jsoup fine.

However, when I run my app, one of my activities calls methods from Jsoup.  Whenever I launch that activity, I get the following error.

```
Could not find method org.jsoup.parse, referenced from method...
VFY: unable to resolve state method 348: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup; parse...
```

Am I not importing it properly?  Why can it not find jsoup?  The above steps seem to be the answer to all the questions on importing a 3rd party jar to Android in eclipse.

My best guess is that eclipse can see the jsoup.jar, but it does not package up the parts I need with the app, so the app is unable to use them.  Not sure if that's it, but if it is, how would I force eclipse to package it so the app can use it from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the Eclipse function `Organize Imports` by pressing Shift+Alt+O and that should take care of everything.